# Does the boundary of the Mandelbrot set $M$ have empty interior?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I am interested in the topological dimension of the boundary $\partial M$ of the Mandelbrot set. While it is known that $\partial M$ has Hausdorff dimension 2, and $M$ has topological dimension 2 (being a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with nonempty interior), I am not so sure about $\partial M$. A theorem (Theorem 6.8.11) in Engelking, Topology, A Geometric Approach states that a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ has topological dimension $m$ iff $int (A)\neq \emptyset$, so it would be sufficient to know if the interior is empty or not.

So does anyone have an idea or a source to point to? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Isn't the interior of a boundary always empty (each open nhbhd of a point of the boundary intersects both the set and its complement)?

Comment: Oh of course.. thanks a lot!

Comment: Knowing that $\partial M$ is has empty interior as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^m$ is sufficient to tell you that $M$ is 2-dimensional (in the topological sense), and lets you know that $\partial M$ is not 2-dimensional.    To show that $\partial M$ is 1-dimensional, you would need to (using your definition) find a way to regard it as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.  Alternatively, you might consider looking at a slightly more general notion, such as the inductive dimension.